# update the database in multiple activities

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am here again to ask for help, now i will give details on my problem hoping someone can solve it : in the first activity `onClick`  the method insert is executed

```
 public class ActivityUn extends Activity {

   final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
  final String ID = "id";
 DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
  public void  ajouter(View v) {

    db.open();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
       long id = db.insertMENAGE(rm_1ts,rm_2ts,rm_3ts);

      prefs.edit().putLong(ID, id).commit();
           db.close();
      }
```

the second activity code is :

```
   public class ActivityDeux  extends Activity {


    SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    long id = prefs.getLong(ID, 0);

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
     public void  ajouter(View v) {
        db.open();


        db.insertMENAGE2(id,a16,b17,rm_18_1ts,rm_18_2ts,c19,d20,e21);
        db.close();                     
        }
```

and here the two methods insert and update ...

```
 public long insertMENAGE(String Region, String Provence_prefecture ,StringCommune_Arrondissement) {
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
      initialValues.put(col_Region,Region);
      initialValues.put(col_Provence_prefecture ,Provence_prefecture);
      initialValues.put(col_Commune_Arrondissement,Commune_Arrondissement);
       return db.insert(MENAGE,null, initialValues);
  }
```

In the second activity I will update the same table by completing remaining columns in the row :

```
  public void insertMENAGE2(int id, int a16, int b17) {
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(col_Type_habitat,a16);
      values.put(col_Statut_occupation ,b17);
      db.update(MENAGE,values,_id+"="+id, null);
}
```

Now , I want to indicates the `id (  primary key )` of the row in table which is Inserted Last ,

I already looked for solutions but they  are not adapted to my situation, since i have other activities updating the same table

And i need to indicates each time that the `id` concerned is the last one inserted.

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use another table to keep the last updated primary key???? which will be updated whenever the activities updates the table you need to track?

Comment: well, i thought first to create for each activity her own table, but first they are many activities, second i need all the info in one table for mutiple analyses..thanks for responding !

Comment: my issue that i don't know how in the methode update to refer to the last id inserted !!

Comment: check my answer...hope i understood in right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
public class ActivityUn extends Activity {

    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final String ID = "id";
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    public void  ajouter(View v) {
        db.open();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        long id = db.insertMENAGE(rm_1ts,rm_2ts,rm_3ts);
        prefs.edit().putLong(ID, id).commit();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

public class ActivityDeux  extends Activity {

```
    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    final String ID = "id";
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

     public void  ajouter(View v) {
        db.open();
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        long id = prefs.getLong(ID, 0);
        //update the value in the table with the id you get from Sharedpreferences
        db.insertMENAGE2(id,a16,b17,rm_18_1ts,rm_18_2ts,c19,d20,e21);
        db.close();                     
    }
}
```

You where usin 2 SharedPreferences variables in the second Activity. The second one (the one you were using) was not instantiated. This would throw a NullPointer Exception.
Please read the documentation about SQLite and SharedPreferences on [developer.google.com](http://developer.google.com) and try to understand what the code does. Also try to avoid french words in your code, whenever someone from a non french speaking country has to read/edit your code it may not make sence to them.

Comment: what about other activities ??

Comment: You can store the latest inserted ID in SharedPreferences, and use it to update the table.

Comment: i should tell you that i already did this method update for all other activities so i can not change and start again, what i am looking for that in the same methode update , there will be a way to refer to the last id , thanks for idea :)

Comment: just do:
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  long id = insertMENAGE(String Region, String Provence_prefecture ,StringCommune_Arrondissement);
  prefs.edit().putLong(ID, id).commit();

Comment: well i will try it, but how could i inserted in the code ? i mean how to make the connection to the update method ? could you edit the solution please

Comment: just pas the ID you get from SharedPreferences to the insertMENAGE2 method. I Updated my code, check the answer

Comment: thanks now the solution is clear, and i am trying to see the results, but how could i define PREFS_NAME and ID ?? are they constants ?? this is the first time i use this !

Comment: Yes they are constants, in Java the convention is to use all uppercase letters for constants and underscores. Examples: PREFSNAME or PREFS_NAME. The prefs name is something you can choose yourself, note that you have to use the same name to get the same preference file.

Comment: well i tried many ways, but it didn't work i will edit my question with full code, hopefully you can notice something !

Answer (score 1):

Its just like doing an synchronization job you looking for.

I suggest you to use a new table with only one value as 'id'

use a method to update that value. say `updatelastupdated(idofinsertedrow)`

call this method while inserting the data in the table

```
public long insertMENAGE(String Region, String Provence_prefecture ,StringCommune_Arrondissement) 

{

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
      initialValues.put(col_Region,Region);
      initialValues.put(col_Provence_prefecture ,Provence_prefecture);
      initialValues.put(col_Commune_Arrondissement,Commune_Arrondissement);
      updatelastupdated(id) //ADD this method here..
       return db.insert(MENAGE,null, initialValues);

 }
```

now the new table `idoftheinsertedrow` cell will always has the `id(Primary key)` you looking for use that for completing the updation in the table.

To explain you clearly

yourtable say `x`

activity 1 inserting  a row of id 1

activity 2 inserting a row  of id 2

activity 3 inserting a row  of id 3

now you have another method `update()` which must update the row of `id 3`

for this i suggest keep another table say `y`

when ever you insert into the table `x` you update the value of `idupdated` in table `y`

so always the `idupdated` column will hold the last row updated in table `x`